# How do I assign the controlling terminal to other process?

Tags: linux, tty, ioctl, controlling-terminal

I use `TIOCSCTTY` to forcibly take over the controlling terminal in other "remote" application. But after the application finishes running, controlling terminal gets orphaned and `bash` stops reacting to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> until I restart it with `bash$ exec bash`.

How should I explicitly return the controlling terminal back after taking it with `TIOCSCTTY`?